# aws-s3 error: AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey error, but keys have been defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm pretty new to ROR. I've recently deployed an app on heroku and have tried to add an attachment function to the app via paperclip.

I've followed all the steps in adding aws-s3 to my app. Here was my initial code:

user.rb (model)

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles => {:small => "70x70>"},
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                  :path => ":attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"


validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

s3.yml (file is located in config folder) note: all of these buckets exist on my aws-s3

```
development:
  bucket: my_avatar-dev
  access_key_id: amazonaccesskey
  secret_access_key: amazon_secret_access_key
test:
  bucket: myapp_avatar-test
  access_key_id: amazonaccesskey
  secret_access_key: amazon_secret_access_key
production:
  bucket: myapp_avatar-pro
  access_key_id: amazonaccesskey
  secret_access_key: amazon_secret_access_key
```

gemfile

```
gem 'aws-s3'
```

When running this configuration, I would get a error page 500 error when loading my app. Running `Heroku logs` showed the following error: **AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey (You did not provide both required access keys.**

So I followed some advice and defined the key and secret_key as environment variables to heroku, using the following line of code:

```
heroku config:add S3_KEY=amazonaccesskey S3_SECRET=amazon_secret_key
```

I then added an initializer to test environments and launch via key or .yml file depending on environment, code is as follows:

initializers/s3.rb

```
if Rails.env == "production"
  # set credentials from ENV hash
  S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'], :bucket => "myapp_avatar-pro"}
else
  # get credentials from YML file
  S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
end
```

user.rb model was then update to the following:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
```

I then deployed to heroku and tested the app, but I still keep getting the same error (page 500) and error code: **AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey (You did not provide both required access keys.**

How is this possible if I have defined the variables in heroku? Is there something I am missing? Is it possible it's something with the gem? Also, I'm using HAML for styling... not sure that matters at all, but just in case it does. I'm quite lost, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: did you figure out the answer?  I am coming across the same issue.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just worked through the same problem and trawling a number of similar posts. I found that any of the possible configurations  in the above answer i.e. declaring all of the hashes in the model, using the .yml or using the initializer all work fine from my dev and on heroku as long as the S3 bucket is of US Standard type> The choice is just about how DRY you want to be.

When I originally set S3 up, I used a European bucket. This gave me the spurious error message:

**AWS::S3::MissingAccessKey (You did not provide both required access keys.**

I note from the AWS site : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/index.html?rande.html 
that AWS uses a specific endpoint address for each region to reduce latency and am guessing (because I am a novice coder) that the US standard is either a default or coded into the AWS-S3 plugin. (Maybe someone can edit this up into a more complete answer?)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this:

```
:s3_credentials => {
  :access_key_id => 'mykey',
  :secret_access_key => 'mykey'
```